# ASP.NET dynamically generating bootsrap panels at runtime

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im designing an advertisement website, where each product is displayed as a Bootstrap Tile, together with a name, photo, cost in the panel. What i want is that whenever i load the page, ASP automatically query the database to find out how many products there are, create that number of tiles and also place the relevant name, photo and cost in each panel.

How can i do this with VB.net?

Here is my HTML panel:

```
     <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Product ID</strong>, Product Name</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a class="thumbnail">
                <img src="Photo.jpg"  /></a></div>

           <div class="panel-footer">
               ProductPrice
           </div>
```

Comment: Where are you having problems? Show your current code, issues and all, for trying to create these dynamically. And tell us where it fails; errors, etc.

Comment: Im very new in ASP, so i wanted direction as to how to approach it.I dont really know how to do it at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an asp ListView or Repeater. It will repeat your template for each item.

```
 <asp:ListView id="PanelList" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><strong><%#Eval("PRODUCTID") %></strong>, <%#Eval("PRODUCTNAMEE") %></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <a class="thumbnail">
                            <img src='<%#Eval("PHOTO") %>' /></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-footer">
                       <%#Eval("PRODUCTPRICE") %>
                    </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Dont forget to assign your ListView control the DataSource on CodeBehind once you recover it from database.

```
PanelList.DataSource = YourCollection;
PanelList.DataBind();
```

Your eval fields should match the name of an accessible property or field on your collection.

Comment: thankyou! Worked like a charm! What is the difference between Listview and repeater?
Also how can i make it repeat in blocks of 6? As in <div class="row">  6 repeated blocks </div>, <div class="row">  6 repeated blocks </div> and so on?